# Objeto superglobal en php

Tags: php

Tengo claro que para almacenar algún dato de manera global persistente para que sea accesible desde cualquier archivo en php se debe utilizar las variables de sesión.

Pero al parecer esta no puede almacenar objetos, sólo arrays y poco más.

**¿Existe alguna manera de simular esto?**

El objeto que tengo tiene variables que almacenan sockets abiertos y creo que eso no se puede almacenar bien.

Comment: Por lo que pones en los comentarios, el problema que tienes parece que es diferente a lo que preguntas. Tienes una variable de tipo socket y quieres que sea persistente, ¿no? ¿Cómo estás creando los sockets? ¿Has mirado [`pfsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pfsockopen.php)?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué uso le quieres dar? Te he dado explicaciones en mi respuesta, pero si me dices qué quieres conseguir te puedo aconsejar qué método usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente estás planteando varias preguntas simultáneamente, algunas se pueden hacer y otras no.

**¿Se puede guardar un objeto en una variable super global?** Sí

```
function pruebas() {
  var_dump($GLOBALS['prueba']);
}

class prueba {
 private $a = 5;
 public $b = 8;
}

$GLOBALS['prueba'] = new prueba();
pruebas();
```

**¿Se puede guardar un objeto en una variable de sesión?** Sí

```
session_start();

class prueba {
 private $a = 5;
 public $b = 8;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['prueba'])) {
  echo "<p>Creando</p>\n";
  $_SESSION['prueba'] = new prueba();
} else {
  echo "<p>Ya estaba creado</p>\n";
}
var_dump($_SESSION['prueba']);
```

**¿Se puede guardar un recurso en una variable de sesión?** NO

No se pueden guardar recursos que puedan ser utilizados entre diferentes ejecuciones de scripts PHP porque éstos se cierran al finalizar la ejecución, los descriptores de archivos (entre los que se encuentran los sockets) se liberan también al finalizar la ejecución, por lo que no se pueden reutilizar.

**Conexiones a sockets o bases de datos persistentes**

Hay mucha confusión en este tema: existen soluciones para reutilizar conexiones previamente establecidas (como [sockets TCP o UNIX](http://php.net/pfsockopen) o [conexiones a bases de datos](http://php.net/persistent-connections) persistentes), pero no se te garantiza de ninguna manera que será exactamente la misma conexión la que se utilice en la siguiente vez que te conectes.

Si se intenta abrir un socket o conexión a base de datos que está siento utilizada por otro script, se creará una nueva conexión para satisfacer la necesidad de tu script.

En la documentación de PHP acerca de [conexiones a bases de datos persistentes](http://php.net/persistent-connections) puede leerse:

> Aquellos que no están plenamente familiarizados con la forma en que
>   trabajan y distribuyen la carga los servidores web podrían confundir
>   para qué sirven las conexiones persistentes. En particular, con ellas
>   no se pueden abrir «sesiones de usuario» en un mismo enlace, no se
>   puede construir una transacción eficiente y no hacen muchísimas otras
>   cosas. De hecho, para ser sumamente precisos, las conexiones
>   persistentes no proporcionan ninguna otra funcionalidad que no fuera
>   posible realizar con sus hermanas no persistentes.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, para almacenar objetos en memoria podrías usar algo como [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (traducción mía):

> Sistema distribuido de cacheo de datos y objetos gratuito, de código libre, de alto rendimiento, genérico por naturaleza, pero con el objetivo de ser usado para acelerar aplicaciones web dinámicas al aliviar la carga de la base de datos.
>
> Memcached es un almacenamiento de clave-valor en memoria para pequeños grupos de datos arbitrarios (cadenas, objetos) para resultados de llamadas a bases de datos, llamadas a APIs o renderizado de páginas.
>
> Memcached es simple pero poderoso. Su diseño simple promueve una rápida distribución, facilidad de desarrollo, y resuelve muchos problemas que se encuentran las cachés de datos grandes. Su API está disponible para muchos lenguajes diferentes.

---

Pero por lo que pones en los comentarios, el problema que tienes parece que es diferente a lo que preguntas. Tienes una variable de tipo socket y quieres que sea persistente. Eso es algo que quizás podrías conseguir abriendo el socket con [`pfsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pfsockopen.php) (énfasis mío):

> pfsockopen - Abre Internet persistente o conexión de socket de dominio Unix
>
> Esta función se comporta exactamente como fsockopen() con la diferencia de que **la conexión no se cierra después de que el script termina**. Esta es la versión persistente de fsockopen().

Aunque debe ser un socket de dominio UNIX, que no sé si es tu caso.

Answer (score -2):

Yo creo que deberías usar una base de datos o un fichero (preferiblemente la primera).

Te creas una tabla de RAM y lo haces ahí, la sesión no es un sitio correcto para guardar gran cantidad de datos.

Es la mejor manera de hacerlo persistente entre distintas peticiones. Puedes usar un numero de sesion para identificar dentro de estas tablas al usuario en cuestion.

Comment: No me vale lo que me comentas. Quiero tener un objeto con sus métodos de forma global de tal forma que por ejemplo: si en __fichero1.php__ se utiliza `$gestion->conectar()` . en __fichero2.php__ se pueda utilizar `$gestion->consumir()`  sin tener que pasar por conectar

Comment: Eso debe pasar por un fichero, puedes generar un json y usar ese json como fichero, y como nombre del fichero un ID aleatorio generado para cada usuario o el ID de sesion... al final se trata de serializar un objeto... o lo haces con un archivo (json) o tal vez te abres un semaforo / socket... pero me parece mas complejo

Comment: Interesante. Pero hasta donde yo sé, no se puede guardar en un fichero una conexión de este tipo `$conex = mysqli_connect() `.

Comment: Pero si es un mysql_connect para que quieres guardarla, se abre por cada petición, así es como se hace, cada php hace el mysqli, es muy eficiente, no te preocupes por abrir la peticion incluso varias miles de veces por segundo... es lo que hacen todas las paginas, nadie comparte la peticion abierta.

Comment: Realmente lo que tengo es una variable de tipo socket, donde la conexión tarda bastante en establecerse cada vez que realiza una petición. Por lo que quiero mantener la conexión (socket) abierta para cada sesión de usuario abierta.

Comment: Las llamadas serían desde navegador o son sin limite de tiempo de ejecución?